# Setting RowDefitions in code and overwriting the existing ones

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

This is my `XAML` Grid:

```
        <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="15,0,15,0" x:Name="grid_forPic" >

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/> <!--neds to be overridden-->
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Now I need to completely override the row definitions at position 5.
I am adding a picture to said row and even when I set the height of this row in `XAML` the picture will completely ignore the set height from `XAML` and just take its own hight. Now I believe forcing the row definitions again after the pic has been set should be at least a workaround.

Can someone overwrite this for me in `C#`? thank you!

Comment: [`auto`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#rows-and-columns) will give it the height it requested so it is normal behavior, are you setting `HeightRequest` in your image?

Comment: Yes I am setting it, but it is completely ignored. HightRequest seems very buggy to me.

Comment: Then why are you declaring here . Declare the grid in code

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to do? Do you have more code concerning adding the image? What are the properties you're giving said image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the Height of the `Grid.RowDefinitions`,you could try below method:

```
grid_forPic.RowDefinitions[4].Height = new GridLength(100);// here change the height of the fifth row to 100         
grid_forPic.ForceLayout();
```